# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS not creating shortcut

Tags: intellij

I am having problems with the IntelliJ installation. The installer wont create a shortcut so I do have to start IntelliJ every time with the "./idea.sh" command. Which is pretty enoying if you everytime have to navigate there to start IntelliJ.

Version: 2018.2
Build: 182.3684.101

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2

If I could get some advices/help I would be very thankful. I am relatively new to Linux so I would really love an instruction :S

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. After you started IDEA IDE, right click on the IDE icon that shows up on the panel and select add to favourite. Then after you close the app, the icon will remain on the panel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 26):

It is quite simple, in the main menu before opening a project there is a quick setting which will add IntelliJ as shortcut in Ubuntu. Go to "Configure" in the lower right corner and then select "Create Desktop entry".

[image: Picture showing how to create a shortcut on Ubuntu]

Comment: Any ideas what if the option isn't there?

Comment: Update IntelliJ to the newest version maybe? @Rogol

Comment: nope, this one helped me: gist.github.com/rob-murray/6828864

Comment: Note: if you want this to be available in your left sidebar, open the Activities search (via _Activities_ button at top-left of desktop, or via Windows key), search for IntelliJ, then drag the IntelliJ shortcut onto your left sidebar. (At least, this is what I needed to do on Ubuntu 22.04.)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Dominik's answer, you can take the command line approach. Assuming that your IntelliJ installation files reside in `/opt/idea/bin`,

#### Create a Desktop Entry to show up in Activities

1. Create the file `/usr/share/applications/idea.desktop`. `touch`, `vi` or `nano` should work, if you have `sudo` enabled.
2. In that file, enter this:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=13.0
    Type=Application
    Terminal=false
    Icon[en_US]=/opt/idea/bin/idea.png
    Name[en_US]=IntelliJ Idea
    Exec=/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh
    Name=Idea
    Icon=/opt/idea/bin/idea.png
```

3. To make absolutely sure you have the right permissions, run the following two commands:

```
chmod 0644 /usr/share/applications/idea.desktop
chown root:root /usr/share/applications/idea.desktop
```

Et voilà!

#### Make a shortcut on your local Desktop

1. Copy the file you created above into your local Desktop directory

   `cp /usr/share/applications/idea.desktop /home/[user.name]/Desktop/`
2. Adjust file permissions as appropriate

   `chmod 0755 /home/[user.name]/Desktop/idea.desktop`

Et voilà!

Answer (score 0):

For recent versions of Idea(~2024) the options are here

[image]